# Probability of error in estimation

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

We are given the cumulative partition function of the rainy days in march and july. We have a paper, without the name of the month (but we know it is one of these two), on which 14 rainy days are noted. What is the best guess  that you would make about the page, is it for the month of march or july? What is the probability that your guess is wrong?

For the first part, i would say that the paper is from march because $P(X=14) = P(X \le 14) - P(X \le 13)$ and this is maximized if we take the month of march ($P(X=14)= 36,01 - 23,66 = 12,35$). Now how do i calculate the probability that i am wrong? Would it be $1-\frac{12,35}{12,35+ 5,63}$?

Comment: Looks good to me, assuming (reasonably) that "14 are noted" means "exactly 14 are noted".

Comment: A Bayesian would ask you if you have any *a priori* reason to prefer March or July.  If not—if they are equally likely before your analysis—then your reasoning appears sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, the approach is fine.